# Checking a character within a String

Tags: java, string, character

I have this code

```
if(!(lotNo.charAt(0) >= "0" && (lotNo.charAt(0) <= "7"))) {
    // if the first character is not within these boundaries
    return false;
}
return true;
```

This method leaves me with an error saying `bad operator type`? Although it was supposed to check whether the first character in a String was between 0 and 7. Am I on the right lines?

Comment: Cheers everyone, I didn't even know there was a difference between "" and ''? You have all saved me hours of stress :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing to strings instead of chars. Try:

```
if (!(lotNo.charAt(0) >= '0' && (lotNo.charAt(0) <= '7'))) { // if the first character is not within these boundaries
    return false;
}
return true;
```

`"0"` <-- String with one char, `'0'`
`'0'` <-- char, the character `'0'`

Answer (score 2):

`Char` must be within `'0'` not `"0"`. The second one is a `String`

Answer (score 0):

charAt(int index) method return value type is char . 
But you are comparing it with a String that's why you get `bad operator type`